# How to add a child to form builder inside an extension?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.8

This might be a very easy question for Symfony experts, but for me, a noob in this technology this is difficult. I have a task to put in a color picker near the text boxes when colors are involved. I have read a lot of articles about forms, form items, extensions and so on in the Symfony documentation and came up with the idea of extending `TextType` by adding a color picker child to the form builder. The class for color pickers already exists. This is my code:

```
<?php

namespace Pph\App\SingBundle\Form\Extension;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractTypeExtension;
use My\Name\Space\ColorPickerType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

/**
 * TextTypeColorPickerExtension.
 *
 * This is an extension to TextType form field, to allow color picker usage when colors are involved
 *
 * @author some dude
 */
class TextTypeColorPickerExtension extends AbstractTypeExtension
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('text', ColorPickerType::class, array(
            'required' => false,
            'empty_data' => '',
        ));
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getExtendedType()
    {
        return TextType::class;
    }
}
```

And this, understandably ends up with infinite recursion. This does not handle the logic with colors yet, that will be a next step, for now I am experimenting with extending `TextType`. Can I somehow mark my `TextType` object after the color picker is added to stop somehow the recursion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that `ColorPickerType` added a `TextType`, so my attempt with the `class` of `TextTypeColorPickerExtension` was unsound, since it created an endless cycle with the following steps:

- `TextType` is added
- `ColorPickerType` is added to `TextType` due to the extension
- `TextType` is added to `ColorPickerType` due to the implementation of `ColorPickerType`

and so on and on and on...

I have solved my problem with a logic, which determined whether TextType or ColorPickerType is needed to be added.